# Mac OS Snow Leoperd

Tags: macos, cocoa, installation, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I want to test my cocoa application on mac os 10.6 (Snow Leoprrd) . But there are 10.7.5 is installed on my system . How can we install  mac os 10.6 on my system , i have downloaded .dmg file of mac os 10.6 , I have use VMWare but there is no luck error occures that "This os is not mac os x server'. Is there any way to install this os virtually or directly on any system of mac os .

```
 Thanks
```

Comment: Very unlikely.  I attempted to install 10.6 on my 2013 iMac and it would not have it.  I then tried on VMWare fusion and it would not have it either (same error message as yours).  Not sure if I tried OSX 10.6 Server or not (pretty sure I didn't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an external hard drive you can install the OS to that drive and boot up directly from there to test out your software. This works great and allows you to run the OS in a full native environment instead of using a VM.

Alternatively you could still go the VM route, but keep in mind that it might be trial and error. This article has a step-by-step guide to install Snow Leopard with VMWare:

http://macs.about.com/od/windowsonyourmac/ss/Virtualization-Of-Leopard-And-Snow-Leopard-Using-Vmware-Fusion.htm

Comment: I have use also external usb drive for boot . I have created boot up and select this drive as a startup drive but when i select , then there appeares dos prompt on which a pop up appeares including message "Please power off of your system then again on it" . I have done may times but it is not worked . Have you any other solution then please tell me .

Comment: Hi Ashish,

That shouldn't be the case.. it is definitely possible to install snow leopard to an external HD.  I've used this guide successfully, let me know if that works for you:

http://www.maciverse.com/installing-snow-leopard-onto-an-external-hard-drive.html